How do I fix error "API call to drive.revisions.update failed with error: Revision not found: 1."
I have a script that I use to change google slides URLs in a spreadsheet to published with anyone can view. The script used to run fine but recently I keep getting the error "API call to drive.revisions.update failed with error: Revision not found: 1."
The script I use is:
function FileID() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"); // Replace "Sheet1" with your actual sheet name
  
  if (sheet) {
    for (var i = 3; i <= 100; i++) {
       if (sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue().split("/")[4] === "u") {
            folderID = sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue().split("/")[7];
            } else {
              folderID = sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue().split("/")[5];
              }
              sheet.getRange("D" + i).setValue(folderID)

             {sharetoanyone = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getRange("D" + i).getValue());  
              sharetoanyone.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
               Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, folderID, 1) 
               }}}}

I have tried to retrieve the revision Id for each slide deck but I can't work out how to code this or if this is the issue.

Maybe check if the revision id exists. Check Method: revisions.list

You might have to validate that you are getting the correct folderID. Please add a [mcve]. You might start by created a function having assigning literal (a value written in the code editor, rather than reading/calculating it) to folderID.
